# Ошибка при работе с библиотекой instabot

Tags: python, python-3.x

В общем, работаю с библиотекой **instabot**. Установил ее, все либы, которые были прописаны в requirements для данной библиотеке так же установилось. Однако при выполнении данного кода:

```
from instabot import Bot
from config import INST_PASSWORD, INST_USERNAME
bot = Bot()
bot.login(username=INST_USERNAME,  password=INST_PASSWORD)
```

Выполнение завершается данной ошибкой:

```
2022-06-29 18:37:20,309 - INFO - Instabot version: 0.117.0 Started
2022-06-29 18:37:20,311 - INFO - Not yet logged in starting: PRE-LOGIN FLOW!
2022-06-29 18:37:22,359 - WARNING - HTTPSConnectionPool(host='i.instagram.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/accounts/get_prefill_candidates/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000027A0D0B3160>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение'))
2022-06-29 18:37:24,399 - WARNING - HTTPSConnectionPool(host='i.instagram.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/qe/sync/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000027A0D118130>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение'))
2022-06-29 18:37:26,446 - WARNING - HTTPSConnectionPool(host='i.instagram.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/launcher/sync/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000027A0D118460>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение'))
2022-06-29 18:37:28,482 - WARNING - HTTPSConnectionPool(host='i.instagram.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/accounts/contact_point_prefill/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000027A0D0B3F40>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение'))
```

Я думаю, что, возможно, это происходит из-за недоступности инстаграма на территории России в данный момент. Если кто-то знает, понимает, в чем проблема - скажите, пожалуйста. Возможно, у кого-то есть идеи по vpn`у.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо прописать прокси или задеплоить его на заграничных серверах.
Из официальной документации:
login — Method that authenticates you in Instagram.

Parameters:

**login, password** — you could pass login and password and bot would use them. Bot would ask you for them by default.

force — forses bot to re-login. False by default.

**proxy** — proxy server that bot would use during authentication.

use_cookie — means that bot would use cookies not to re-login every time it needs to push some request. Defaults as True.

cookie_fname — filename where cookies would be stored. Default value: cookie.txt.

То есть:

```
from instabot import Bot

bot = Bot
bot.login(username="***", password="***", proxy="***")
```

Попробуй так. Должно помочь. Или еще, как вариант, когда запускаешь бота в терминале пайчарма, включать впн на компьютере.